# Unity RPG, spellcast correctly not using mana, but damage still going through

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a Skill that both, uses mana and does damage to the enemy. I have succesfuly made it so that if my players mana < the cost of the skill then it will not use any mana. The problem is that even though it wont use mana the skill still is used and the damage goes through.

**Unit.cs**

```
public void UseMana(int spellcost)
{
    if (currentMP >= spellcost)
    {
        currentMP -= spellcost;
    }
}
```

**BattleSystem.cs**

```
IEnumerator Skill1Use()
{
    playerUnit.UseMana(10);

    
    playerHUD.SetMP(playerUnit.currentMP);

     

    bool isDead = enemyUnit.TakeDamage(Convert.ToInt32(playerUnit.damage * 1.2));

    
    enemyHUD.SetHP(enemyUnit.currentHP);
    dialogueText.text = "The attack is successful";
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

    if (isDead)
    {
        state = BattleState.WON;
        EndBattle();
    }
    else
    {
        state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
        StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could instead return a `bool` as a check if it was succesfull:

```
public bool UseMana(int spellcost)
{
    if (currentMP >= spellcost)
    {
        currentMP -= spellcost;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then do

```
IEnumerator Skill1Use()
{
    // if the mana was not successful break here and do nothing
    if(!playerUnit.UseMana(10))
    {
        dialogueText.text = "Not enough Mana for the attack! :(";
        yield break;
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that even though it wont use mana the skill still is
> used and the damage goes through.

Currently you aren't checking if the user actually has enough mana to cast the spell. The easiest way to implement that would be to make the UseMana Function return a bool and then use that to exit out of the Skill1Use Enum.

If you want to display a message when the casting has failed you can put it into the UseMana function.

**Changed UseMana Function:**

```cs
public bool UseMana(int spellcost)
{
    if (currentMP >= spellcost) {
        // Remove Mana used for the spell
        currentMP -= spellcost;
        // Player could cast the spell
        return true;
    }

    // Message to User because his spell casting failed
    Debug.Log("Casting Spell failed.");
    
    // Player could not cast the spell
    return false;
}
```

These return values can we now use to return out of the Enum.

```cs
IEnumerator Skill1Use()
{
    if (!playerUnit.UseMana(10)) {
        // Return out of the Enumerator
        yield break;
    }
    
    .....
}
```

If you don't want to skip the whole Enumerator with `yield break;` when the Player couldn't cast the spell, you can switch around the if-statement and include all code that depends on the casting of the spell into that if-statement.

**Skipping only certain parts of the Enumerator Code:**

```cs
IEnumerator Skill1Use()
{
    if (playerUnit.UseMana(10)) {
        // Player executed the spell so we can now do our calculations now
        .....
    }
    // Player couldn't cast the spell so we can skip damage calculations, 
    // death check and setting the UI
    else {
        .....
    }
    
    .....
}
```

Comment: `yield return null;` is wrong (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132655/7111561)) .. `yield return null;` only delays one frame but continues with the routine .. in order to exit of an `IEnumerator` you have to use `yield break;`

Comment: Thanks wasn't sure how to exit out of an enum again.

Comment: so yeah basically now we are saying exactly the same ;)

Comment: thanks heaps guys! amazed how quick people respond on here. its now working and nothing is done if the button is clicked with not enough mana. Now if I want a text to show up saying something like "not enough mana" where would i put that in the code.

Comment: @mookalicious I edited my answer accordingly, if you want to actually show it to the user isntead of just printing a message to the console you would probably need to enable a panel gui to simulate a popup.

Comment: hey guys, after playing around a bit I realised that as you said the yield break; stops the enum. but it then does not allow me to use any of the other commands could this be that i have battle states such as playerturn etc. is there a way to make it play another enum instead of completing stopping the current one. sorry am new to this so let me know if i dont make sense.

Comment: @mookalicious I added some code hope it explains what you would need to do to execute the code only if the spell was actually executed.

Comment: @mookalicious please stick to the original scope of your question. If you have follow up questions please re-take your own time, investigate, try stuff and only if you can't figure it out on your own come back here with a new question ;)